# Endless loop in .htaccess when rewrite to a folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got the root of my domain with some folders.

- app
- scripts
- shop

And I want to redirect with the .htaccess everything to the folder **shop**, except **app** and **scripts**. I wrote the next .htaccess, but I've got a 500 ERROR INTERNAL SERVER. I saw the log file and it says that there is and endless loop.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/scripts
RewriteRule (.*)$ shop/$1 [L]
```

I have another hosting with other apps and cms in the same hosting provider. Even with the same structure and it works perfect, then I don't undertand why doesn't work here.

How can I avoid the endless loop?

**EDIT**: I want that the redirect will be invisible, not with [R]

**EDIT 2**: My purpose is:
Having this folders:

- app
- scripts
- shop

Access to the shop folder with the URL: **domain.com**
Access to the app folder with: **domain.com/app**
Access to the scripts folder with: **domain.com/scripts**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll also have to exclude URLs beginning with `shop`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ /shop/ [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /shop(/\S*)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop / [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(app|scripts|shop)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shop/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I want that the redirect will be invisible, not with [R]

Comment: @NachoSoler Just don't put the `R` flag.

Comment: But then, I can access to the shop with http://domain.com/shop
Could we avoid this?

Comment: @NachoSoler Can you explain what you mean to avoid? If you want the explicit URL `http://domain.com/shop` to be inaccessible, put: `RewriteRule ^shop/?$ - [F]` just after `RewriteEngine` line.

Comment: That doesn't work.
I want the rewrite to be invisible. I have a path with **shop**, but I want access with **http://domain.com**, not **http://domain.com/shop**

Comment: I still do not understand what you're expecting. Can you provide details in the question itself?

Comment: Okei, sorry. Maybe my English is not enough. I write it as a **EDIT 2**

Comment: It seems that now works perfectly . I am going to study the code. Thank you very much!!